# Incluir dependencias en pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy creando una aplicación en `python` y necesito compilarla en un ejecutable de windows, estoy utilizando `pyinstaller` para eso mediante:

```
C:\usuario>pyinstaller script.py
```

Esto me genera una carpeta con las dependencias y el ejecutable.

El problema radica en que `script.py` importa utilidades  de otros scripts propios, por ejemplo:

```
import script2
import script3

def main():
    #haciendo cosas con script2 y script3
```

al tratar de ejecutar el archivo me marca un error por que no se incluyeron los scripts en la lista de dependencias, quisiera saber como es que puedo agregar dichos scripts en las dependencias.

de antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Es `import script2.py` o `import script2`?, ¿Es un problema tipográfico?

Comment: @eyllanesc No no es un error tipografico, he corregido la pregunta pero el codigo de mi aplicacion esta bien, funciona cuando corro el script, pero no funciona cuando lanzo el ejecutable

Comment: Me referia que era un error tipográfico en el sentido que transcribio mal su codigo al crear la pregunta.

Comment: Revisa este enlace: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html

Comment: @eyllanesc segui tu link y todo funciono de maravilla, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Siempre es bueno leer la documentación :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por fin funciono!!!

gracias al link que me proporciono `eyllanesc` en su comentario pude resolver el problema.

`pyinstaller` puede buscar dependencias externas, lo unico necesario es generar un archivo `.spec` (archivo de especificacion) donde se especifique donde hay que buscar tales dependencias.

**APARIENCIA DE UN ARCHIVO .SPEC**

```
a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\carpetaDelScript'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

esto nos dice que se creara un archivo `.exe`  a partir del archivo `script.py` y que este archivo se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `C:\\carpetaDelScript` definida dentro de la variable `pathex`

**AGREGANDO DEPENDECIAS EXTERNAS**

para generar un archivo `.spec` tenemos que ejecutar el comando:

```
pyi-makespec options name.py
```

y para agregar una ruta de dependencias simplemente agregamos la opcion:

```
--paths=[ruta de dependencias]
```

por lo que el comando completo seria:

```
pyi-makespec --paths=C:\\carpetaDependencias script.py
```

lo que nos generaria un archivo `.spec` similar a:

```
 a = Analysis(['script.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\carpetaDelScript', 'C:\\carpetaDependencias'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[],
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
```

puedes agregar tantas carpetas como necesites

**GENERANDO EL .EXE**

en el proceso anterior generamos un  `.spec` con el mismo nombre que nuestro script, para generar el `.exe` solo ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

```
pyinstaller script.spec
```

esto generara una carpeta llamada `dist` dentro de ella estara nuestro ejecutable.

Comment: esta ruta: 'C:\\carpetaDependencias', es la carpeta con subcarpetas de los modulos o las carpetas de los modulos en si?