# Problemas con módulos al generar un archivo EXE

Tags: python

Creé un proyecto en Python 3.6.4 y estoy utilizando el editor `SublimeText 3.2.2`, dentro del proyecto importé librerías desde `pip install` y también importé módulos creados por mi, al ejecutar el proyecto en Sublime funciona todo perfecto pero cuando creo el ejecutable `.exe` con `pyinstaller`, al abrir la aplicación no encuentra o no reconoce los módulos propios.
Me pone el siguiente error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...

El archivo `.py` se encuentra en el mismo directorio que los módulos propios.

Comment: Hola Claudio, mírate esta otra pregunta [Incluir dependencias en pyinstaller](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130261/15089) a ver si resuelve tu problema. Debes usar la opcion `--patch` de `pyinstaller` e indicarle la ruta para que incluya esos archivos en el bundle o bien generar un archivo .spec y usar el atributo `pathex`. Mírate también la documentación oficial (en ingles) sobre [cmdoption-p](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-p) y [using-spec-files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=spec#using-spec-files) de PyInstaller

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema tuve que crear un archivo .spec para especificar la ruta del directorio que agrupaba los módulos externos